# Trouble with JavaScript Timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble creating a JavaScript timer using. I have tried to implement things from other stack overflow questions and haven't had any success.

When I click the play button, "0-8:0-46" is displayed instead of the actual timer. And it does not count down.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/Jamece/pen/jOazYvQ

My Code thus far is below. I am trying to troubleshoot the sessionTimer function right now.

```
const minTime = 1;
const maxTime = 60;
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breakLength: 5,
      sessionLength: 25,
      started: false,
      mode: "Session"
    };
    this.breakIncrement = this.breakIncrement.bind(this);
    this.breakDecrement = this.breakDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionIncrement = this.sessionIncrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionDecrement = this.sessionDecrement.bind(this);
    this.beginTimer = this.beginTimer.bind(this);
    this.sessionTimer = this.sessionTimer.bind(this);
    this.breakTimer = this.breakTimer.bind(this);
    this.pauseTimer = this.pauseTimer.bind(this);
  }

  breakIncrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.breakLength !== maxTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          breakLength: state.breakLength + 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  breakDecrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.breakLength !== minTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          breakLength: state.breakLength - 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  sessionIncrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.sessionLength !== maxTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          sessionLength: state.sessionLength + 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  sessionDecrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.sessionLength !== minTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          sessionLength: state.sessionLength - 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  beginTimer() {
    this.setState({ started: !this.state.started });
    if (this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.mode == "Session") {
        this.sessionTimer();
      } else {
        this.breakTimer();
      }
    } else {
      this.pauseTimer();
    }
  }
  sessionTimer() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    const sessionTime = setTimeout(() => {
      const distance = this.state.sessionLength - start;
      var minutes = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / 1000);
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      const sessionClock = (document.getElementById("time-left").innerHTML =
        minutes + ":" + seconds);

      if (distance <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(sessionTime);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  breakTimer() {}

  pauseTimer() {}

  render() {
    let pausePlayStyle = this.state.started
      ? "fa-solid fa-pause"
      : "fa-solid fa-play";
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid px-0">
        <div className="main d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <div className="heading">25 + 5 Clock</div>
            <div className="d-flex">
              <div className="d-flex flex-column break align-items-center">
                <div id="break-label" className="mb-3 h3">
                  Break Length
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="break-increment"
                    onClick={this.breakIncrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div className="mx-3 h3" id="break-length">
                    {this.state.breakLength}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="break-decrement"
                    onClick={this.breakDecrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center session">
                <div id="session-label" className="mb-3 h3">
                  Session Length
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="session-increment"
                    onClick={this.sessionIncrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div className="h3 mx-3" id="session-length">
                    {this.state.sessionLength}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="session-decrement"
                    onClick={this.sessionDecrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center timer-border">
              <div className="h2 mb-3 session" id="timer-label">
                {this.state.mode}
              </div>
              <div className="display-1 timer mb-4" id="time-left"></div>
              <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-bottom"
                  id="start_stop"
                  onClick={this.sessionTimer}
                >
                  <i className={pausePlayStyle}></i>
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-bottom" id="reset">
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-rotate"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

The first is that the `setTimeout()` executes the code after the timer expires, it doesn't repeat it every X seconds as you're hoping. In this case the code is called after one second and that's  it. (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Regarding the odd values:

```
const distance = this.state.sessionLength - start;
```

This will always be negative, because sessionLength is 25 by default and start  is a timestamp (e.g. 1645666006168), because `Date().getTime()` (more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns a timestamp. 25 - 1645666006168 is negative and therefore the way you're calculating minutes and seconds will yield a negative value too.

Since you're then trying to concatenate a leading 0 if they are less than 10,  because you're treating the numbers  as strings,  you will just add the 0 before the negative sign:

```
minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes; // 0-8
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds; // 0-46
minutes + ":" + seconds  // 0-8:0-46
```